# Kubernetes grant user/service account privilege to use 'kubectl cp' command

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod which have a java app inside, the java app will watch a directory, and auotmaticly found and load plugin bundle. These bundles are seprate java projects with CI/CD pipelines, now I want to use `kubectl cp` command in my CI/CD scripts to deploy these bundle files, however, I just want to give minimal privileges to CI/CD user, Is that possible using kubernetes's RBAC API?

Comment: Did you read this? https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/

Comment: @muehsi a quick pass, I think that what RBAC can offer is with broader privileges, a role with update verb to my pod for example., not something I am looking for.

Comment: You probably don't want to use `kubectl cp` here.  (What happens if there are multiple replicas of a pod?  What happens if a node fails and Kubernetes reschedules the pod on a different system?)  Have your CI system build a new image, push it to a repository, and have it update the deployment specs to upgrade the running system.

Comment: @DavidMaze you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kubectl cp` internally uses `kubectl exec`. So the RBAC needs to be on the `exec` subresource of `pod`.

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: pod-copy
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/exec"]
  verbs: ["create"]
```

Then you can create `RoleBinding` to assign this role to the service account

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
# This role binding allows "jane" to read pods in the "default" namespace.
# You need to already have a Role named "pod-reader" in that namespace.
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: pod-copy-rolebinding
  namespace: default
subjects:
# You can specify more than one "subject"
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default # "name" is case sensitive
  namespace: default #namespace where service account is created
roleRef:
  # "roleRef" specifies the binding to a Role / ClusterRole
  kind: Role #this must be Role or ClusterRole
  name: pod-copy # this must match the name of the Role or ClusterRole you wish to bind to
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

This will give the service account `default` in `default` namespace to exec into pods in `default` namespace.

The same `RoleBinding` can applied to a `user` as well by mentioning it the `subjects`

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
# This role binding allows "jane" to read pods in the "default" namespace.
# You need to already have a Role named "pod-reader" in that namespace.
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: pod-copy-rolebinding
  namespace: default
subjects:
# You can specify more than one "subject"
- kind: User
  name: Jane # "name" is case sensitive
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  # "roleRef" specifies the binding to a Role / ClusterRole
  kind: Role #this must be Role or ClusterRole
  name: pod-copy # this must match the name of the Role or ClusterRole you wish to bind to
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Comment: how to genertate  ~/.kube/config then ? my CI/CD task runs outside kubernetes cluster

Comment: please ask a different question with details where you want to generate kubeconfig

Answer (score 0):

The minimal RBAC Role for `kubectl cp` looks like this:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: copy-to-pod
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods", "pods/exec"]
  verbs: ["get", "create"]
```